# Adding custom order attribute in order email template

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, custom-attributes, order-email

I created a custom order attribute called `security_string` And a random string is being generated after a order places using `<event>` handle `sales_order_place_after`. String is being generated and it saved into database as well.

Now I have to send this string through order email. So, I have to pass this string to `app/local/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html`.

I extended only `sendNewOrderEmail` method to  `local/Mage` like this `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`

```
<?php

class Mage_Sales_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract
{
    public function sendNewOrderEmail()
    {
     /*Existing Code*/
     if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($this->getCustomerId());
            $securityString = $customerId->getSecurityString();
            $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($this->getCustomerId());
            $securityString = $customerId->getSecurityString();
            $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
        }
        /*Existing Code*/
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
          'order'        =>  $this,
          'billing'      =>  $this->getBillingAddress(),
          'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
          'securityString'  => $securityString
       ));
        $this->queueNewOrderEmail(true);
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

From email template I am trying to access as `{{var order.getSecurityString()}}` but unable to get the value, whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Please show full code of the method. In 1.9 there is no code before calling `queueNewOrderEmail()` like you say "/*Existing Code*/" and I suspect you're mixing up these two methods. `$mailer` is only initialized in queueNewOrderEmail()